# Convert varchar to json and extract from json array

Tags: postgresql

**Background**

I have a table called `purchases` with 3 columns `id`, `purchaser`, and `items_purchased`. The key thing to note is that `items_purchased` is of type varchar. My objective is to be able to select `id`, `purchaser` and `name`,`price` from the `items_purchased` column. It is easy to select `id` and `purchaser`. However, I am having **issue** in extracting from `items_purchased` column. If it was of type `jsonb` life would be easy, but it is not so I am wondering how can I convert the `varchar` to array of JSON (items_purchased) and extract information from each JSON.

**Code**

I have some simple table. Here is the code

```
    CREATE TABLE public.purchases
    (
        id   serial PRIMARY KEY,
        purchaser varchar(50),
        items_purchased varchar(500)
    );

INSERT INTO purchases (purchaser,items_purchased) VALUES ('Bob',
'[{
  "productid": 1,
  "name": "Dell 123 Laptop Computer",
  "price": 1300
},
 {
  "productid": 2,
  "name": "Mechanical Keyboard",
  "price": 120
}
]');
INSERT INTO purchases (purchaser,items_purchased) VALUES('Carol',
'[{
  "productid": 3,
  "name": "Virtual Keyboard",
  "price": 150
}, {
  "productid": 1,
  "name": "Dell 123 Laptop Computer",
  "price": 1300
},
 {
  "productid": 8,
  "name": "LG Ultrawide Monitor",
  "price": 190
}
]');
INSERT INTO purchases (purchaser,items_purchased) VALUES ('Ted',
'[{
  "productid": 6,
  "name": "Ergonomic Keyboard",
  "price": 90
},
 {
  "productid": 7,
  "name": "Dell 789 Desktop Computer",
  "price": 120
}
]');
INSERT INTO purchases (purchaser,items_purchased) VALUES('Alice',
'[{
  "productid": 7,
  "name": "Dell 789 Desktop Computer",
  "price": 120
},
 {
  "productid": 2,
  "name": "Mechanical Keyboard",
  "price": 120
}
]');




SELECT jsonb_array_elements(items_purchased) FROM purchases
```

Here is my [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/1643)

Comment: Consider normalizing the schema and having an extra table for the purchases rather than (ab)using (not even correctly typed) JSON. But anyway, you can cast in Postgres by a) using `cast()` as in `cast(items_purchased AS jsonb)` or the `::` suffix as in `items_purchased::jsonb`. You didn't mention how exactly the data should be extracted -- desired results in tabular from you help -- but since you wrote "If it was of type `jsonb` life would be easy" that should get you going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast the varchar column to jsonb.

```
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(items_purchased::jsonb) FROM purchases;
```

It would be better to alter the table to store the JSON as jsonb. This is more efficient and will validate the JSON.

```
alter table purchases
  alter column items_purchased type jsonb using items_purchased::jsonb;
```

---

This is not a good use of JSON. There's no guarantee any of the customers nor items exist (referential integrity), and will be expensive and difficult to work with their purchases. JSON is not a get-out-of-making-a-good-schema card. It's best used for when you're not sure what data will be stored.

Since the structure is well known and relational, use table relationships.

```
create table customers (
  id bigint generated always as identity primary key,

  -- Do not add arbitrary restrictions to fields in the schema.
  -- Enforce them in the application if necessary.
  name text not null
);

create table items (
  id bigint generated always as identity primary key,
  name text not null,
  price int not null
);

create table items_purchased (
  customer_id bigint not null references customers,
  item_id bigint not null references items,
  
  -- It might differ from items.price, or items.price may change after purchase.
  paid int not null
);

-- First, we'll fix the schema. Then we'll go see Tony Bennett. 
insert into customers(name) values ('Bob'), ('Carol'), ('Ted'), ('Alice');
insert into items(id, name, price) overriding system value values
  (1, 'Dell 123 Laptop Computer', 1300),
  (2, 'Mechanical Keyboard', 120),
  (3, 'Virtual Keyboard', 150),
  (8, 'LG Ultrawide Monitor', 190),
  (6, 'Ergonomic Keyboard', 90),
  (7, 'Dell 789 Desktop Computer', 120);

insert into items_purchased(customer_id, item_id, paid) values
  (1, 1, 1300), (1, 2, 120),
  (2, 3, 150), (2, 1, 1300), (2, 8, 190),
  (3, 6, 90), (3, 7, 120),
  (4, 7, 120), (4, 2, 120);

select
  c.name,
  i.name,
  ip.paid
from
  items_purchased ip
join customers c on c.id = ip.customer_id
join items i on i.id = ip.item_id;
```

[Try it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=11e2a5db5db75eb2e19722950401cfcc).